# Quick question on invertable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let say A is a n x n matrix and it takes $4$ elemental operations to get $A^{-1}$

How many ways can I write $A^{-1}$ and A? Numbered respectively per the operation

For instance: $$A = E_1^{-1}E_2^{-1}E_3^{-1}E_4^{-1} $$

$$A^{-1} = E_4E_3E_2E_1$$

Is there more ways?

Comment: You will need to be more specific about what you mean by a "way" of constructing $A$ or $A^{-1}$ from elementary operations. There are infinitely many ways overall (you can for instance just keep swapping a row back and forth).